# Найти сумму двух текстовых полей

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать что б при нажатии кнопки сумма в текстовом поле вместе была сумма текстового поля премия и доход?
Пробовал так но оно складывает два значения а не суммирует

```html
<h3>Вычисление розмеру премии</h3>
<form name="form1">
  <p>Введите розмер доходу и после этого нажмите"Пощитать"</p>
  Доход: <input type="text" name="num" size="10">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Пощитать" onClick="document.form1.res.value=0.25*document.form1.num.value">
  <br><br> Премия:
  <input type="text" name="res" size="10">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Сумма" onClick="sum.value=num.value+res.value">
  <br><br> Вместе:
  <input type="text" name="sum" size="10">
  <br><br>

  <input type="reset" value="Очистить">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Сумма" onClick="sum.value=(+num.value)+(+res.value)">
```